# How do you install a sfdx plugin with npm and package.json?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, node.js

I'm trying to install a sfdx plugin, and the only install instructions I can find are `sfdx plugins:install plugin-name`.

With modern development practices, we define our project's Node development dependencies in a root `package.json` file. To install and update dependencies and ensure we're using specific versions, we update the `package.json` file to include the project's dependencies, and use `npm` to install and update dependencies. "We" meaning all engineers using Node for the last 10 years.

`sfdx plugins:install` is bad practice for a few reasons:

- It's an extra manual step for all engineers
- It's an extra manual step for build tools
- The version isn't declaratively controllable
- It's against the grain of modern development practices

How can we install a sfdx plugin without forcing manual out of band steps?

If I try this:

```
npm install --save-dev pluginname
```

It works, but sfdx doesn't find the plugin:

```
Warning: pluginname:action is not a sfdx command.
```

Comment: So, I know there's a way (I've seen a plugin that does it), but it depends on the developer to make this happen. I don't know what it is though, but I've asked around for you.

Comment: See [this thread](https://twitter.com/MShaneMc/status/1384679965128462339), includes a link to a [repo that does this](https://github.com/mshanemc/deploy-to-sfdx). Basically, the scripts just do `sfdx plugins:link node_modules/plugin-name` when they need to link various commands. This runs on Heroku automatically, as no out-of-band/manual steps, it's just a matter of linking. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a workaround you can put in place to avoid the extra `sfdx plugin:install` step. Sadly `sfdx` doesn't play very nicely with the Node ecosystem so you still have to jump through a hoop to make it work.

Under the hood `sfdx plugin:install` apparently runs a command to link the plugin install location to somewhere `sfdx` can find it.

To replicate the sfdx behavior without the manual step: install the plugin as normal:

```
npm install --save-dev myplugin
```

Then set up an npm **script** to link and run the package. This isn't great because the `link` has globally polluting side effects on sfdx, but it will work.

Open your root `package.json` file and add something to the `scripts` section, like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "do-the-thing": "sfdx plugins:link node_modules/myplugin && sfdx myplugin --do-whatever"
  },
```

Then to use your plugin, you can run:

```
npm run do-the-thing
```

npm also supports passing arguments to scripts with the bash end-positional-argument separator `--`, such as

```
npm run do-the-thing -- --my-plugin-flag
```

If you really wanted to, you could also run the plugin install command instead in the script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "do-the-thing": "sfdx plugins:install myplugin && sfdx myplugin --do-whatever"
  },
```

This doesn't let you version control the plugin dependency+version though.

I hope `sfdx` matures and becomes more standard in terms of development practices. I've filed a [feature request](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/983) with the project to see if they'll consider supporting this as a first class workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there are other ways, but I typically do the following to make my plugins available for install with npm and package.json.

### 1. Prepare the plugin

We need to expose the binary (`bin/run`) of the plugin.
My recommendation is to use the name of your npm package as binary name (see the notes about `npx` down).

Let's assume you've generated your plugin using the `sfdx plugins:generate sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin` command and your main topic is `hello` (`sfdx hello`).

You would then need to modify the plugin's `package.json` file as follows:

```json
    ...
    "bin": {
        "sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin": "bin/run"
    },
    ...
    "files": {
        "/bin",
        ...
    },
    ...
```

### 2. Install and use the plugin

Assuming you now want to use your plugin in another project called `acme-project`.

Install the plugin with npm inside the `acme-project` directory:

```
npm install --save-dev sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin
```

Now instead of calling your plugin with `sfdx` you'd need to use `npx sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin`:

Example:

Instead of

```
sfdx hello --help
```

use

```
npx sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin hello --help
```

Here `npx sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin` resolves the binary named `sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin` from the package also named `sfdx-plugin-myawesomeplugin`. They can have different names but this keeps the npx command short (see [npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx) docs for more info).

Comment: This looks like a good answer for plugin authors, if you have control over the plugin itself. I'm not sure I even understand why it would be an sfdx plugin (or why anyone would make an sfdx plugin) when all it's doing is running a bin/ file.

Answer (score 1):

I've just recently found another way - without linking plugins to the global installation path or preparing the plugin itself.
So I've documented this approach in an article: https://hutte.io/trails/dependency-management-for-sfdx-projects/

In short, you can install and use sfdx plugins in your sfdx project by setting the environment variable `SFDX_DATA_DIR` to `"$(pwd)"` (the current directory).
This will register the dependency in `package.json` and install it to `./node_modules`.

Example:

```
export SFDX_DATA_DIR="$(pwd)"
sfdx plugins install sfdmu
sfdx sfdmu --help
```

Now other developers will be able to setup their development environment for this sfdx project by running:

```
export SFDX_DATA_DIR="$(pwd)"
yarn install
```

Please note that you'll need to set this environment variable not only for the installation but also when using the plugins. So tools like [direnv](https://direnv.net) might be useful to accomplish that.